# Getting Error : 4020 : Information received from an Invalid IP address

Tags: payment-gateway, opayo

I was using Sagepay form integration version 2.23
Then we need to add Token integration, so did the same what token_system_integration_guideline.pdf said and did Server Integration.. Now while registering token, I'm getting this status message

```
VPSProtocol=2.23 or VPSProtocol=3.00 
Status=INVALID
StatusDetail=4020 : Information received from an Invalid IP address.
```

Getting the same status error while doing payment transaction..

currently I'm working with test server account. i.e. https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/token.vsp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Login to sagepay Simuator portal at https://test.sagepay.com/Simulator/account.asp
2. click the red "Account" button in the corner，
3. add your ip address at "Valid IP Addresses for this Account" part.

Comment: Thanks @Ziegfeld.. I solved this issue, with out using Simulator login, as I don't have account for that... Problem was coming after adding my IP address to the list, then I knew that my PC has shared IP, so tested it on static PC and it's working....

Comment: Thank you for this update! I will take a note about this and let my developer team pay attention not to use shared IP.